# Interpreting part of Irish baptism entry

Tags: 19th-century, surnames, ireland

the usual practice for Irish baptism entries is that the mother's name is usually accompanied by their maiden name and sometimes their married name [same as fathers].

In the entry #2081 attached for Anne McMahon, the mother's last name is missing but there is a squiggle which is unusual. this is the entry that i am interested in for family research.

If you look at entry #2083, the mother's surname is not there but the registrar has recorded "do" which means, as far as i am aware, same as per father's last name. the handwriting suggests the same registrar recorded both entries.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

“Do” is short for “ditto.” So in both cases, the mother’s maiden name appears to have been the same as the father's. (With 2083, Walsh is one of the most common surnames in Ireland so that wouldn’t be too unusual).

Answer (score 0):

2081. Anne of Thomas McMahon & Bridget Do. Where Do means ditto, ie McMahon.